# Image Button always get grayed while getting tapped (touched)

Tags: iphone, uibutton

When ever I add a custom button (image button) and I tap (touch) it then the image button gets grayed out while its being tapped.

Could you please tell me how can I disable this behaviour?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

Just update the "Highlight State Configuration" under Button Attribute and select the same image as in "Default State Configuration".

And its been fixed!!!

Comment: Found one more solution, just disable the "Highlighted Adjusts Image" option under Drawing section of Button Attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property **showsTouchWhenHighlighted** to avoid this behaviour:

```
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the selected state of the image button when it's tapped. Try something like the code below:

UIImage *img = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];

You can set the select color and any other attributes you like, when the button is tapped. This should prevent the button becoming gray when clicked.

Hope that helps!